# Word for the fear that something might not live up to your expectations

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, emotions

"As my big day approached, I was filled with ______ "

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not provide clear criteria for useful answers – criteria that guide both answering and voting. This applies to word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.

Comment: See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: In the case of this question it currently lacks (i) and (iii).

Comment: Please avoid posting requests covered by [“Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity”](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160) from Stack Exchange management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also be looking for *apprehension*:

> 1. anxiety or fear that something bad or unpleasant will happen. "he felt sick with apprehension"

Comment: This may satisfy OP but is a far from satisfactory answer. There is no requirement of 'fear that something might not live up to your expectations'. As an answer to 'fear that something bad might happen', it obviously would fit, but is not of ELU standard.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for  ***[anxiety](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anxiety):***

> an uncomfortable feeling of nervousness or worry about something that is happening or might happen in the future:
>
> - *Children normally feel a lot of anxiety about their first day at school.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)